Comedy audiobook heard on Audible. In the far future the known universe is ruled as an empire by 'Greatest Britain.'
The protagonist Isaac Steele works for the government. He does not however agree with many of their policies. For example he lets an alien who is illegally living on Earth go, when the police would have killed here had they known her illegal status.
Isaac was the victim of illegal experiments as a baby and young child. His throat is modified such that he can speak every language and his meaning gets spoken, not a direct translation of his words.
He has a robot partner, a medical doctor. Sex between humans are aliens is a capital offence but they did sleep together once.
Much of earth is a radioactive wasteland, peopled by mutants who are mostly weak and disadvantaged. One mutant is 'trying to open a restaurant.' He is shaped like a chair.
Mutants are excluded from human society and must live in "The Absence. " The radioactive wasteland.The only exception to this law is the royal family. Its majesty and its offspring are treated like royalty.
Much of human history has been forgotten due to a terrible nuclear war. This event is called The Setback. There is a department of pre-setback technology. Isaac spends most of his time drunk and uses huge quantities of herion.

Downvote from me, I'm afraid. This one seems trivially easy to find, just by searching the name of the main character.

@Valorum It was indeed trivially easy to find. I posted both description and answer together since I thought people here would enjoy it. I was not claiming not to know the answer.

Per the tooltip for downvoting "This question does not show any research effort". And if you knew the answer before you'd even asked the question (of yourself), I'd question the value of posting it.

For the record, I upvoted your (now-deleted) answer. It was well written and concise.

As someone who has a lot of self-answered questions, realizing the answer as you write the question is fair game, but historically people have frowned a bit on people staging the situation just to promote a work. It's kind of a weird situation, since Stack Overflow suggests providing self-answered questions to educate others, but story-id questions are also a bit odd.

My two cents: unlike a site like StackOverflow, where posting a question+answer of a technical problem can be seen as a valuable FAQ instance, in scifi there are no "useful FAQs" and no real "problem to be solved", so there's nothing to be gained by posting a pair of Q+A. Furthermore, there's a near infinite universe of scifi Q&A and this isn't Wikipedia, so not every pair fits here; only questions people actually have. That's why I don't think this behavior (which seems well intended!) fits here.

This is Isaac Steele and the Forever Man by Daniel Rigby

Brought to you by Its Majesty’s Government. Greatest Britain: For a Global Universe.
Agent Isaac Steele has problems. He spends all his splibs on drink and drugs. He has some deep-seated and very much unresolved issues with his parents. And his robotic partner at Greatest Britain’s Department of Clarification, Dr Timothy Stephens, is ruled more by his heart than his hard drive.
But all these issues take a back seat when Isaac stumbles upon a case involving the most sensitive information in the cosmos - a Never File, inaccessible to all except those with the highest clearance. He is expressly forbidden to involve himself. So naturally he does.
So begins an investigation that will take him across the Discovered Universe, into the path of the mysterious Forever Man, and eventually to answers about his past. Along the way, he will have to contend with aliens, robots, monsters, bureaucrats and, perhaps most deadly of all, his own numerous flaws.
Written and narrated by Daniel Rigby (Flowers, Black Mirror), not since The Hitchhiker’s Guide to the Galaxy have listeners been offered such a joyful, anarchic and insightful universe.

